# Change user password using Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient

Tags: .net, azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

I've tried to change user password using ChangeUserPassword method from Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient.
I've even added User.ReadWrite.All, Directory.AccessAsUser.All for b2c app, but it doesn't work.
Is it possible to change password for my users using this method?

When I try to change password I get the following response:
`{"odata.error":{"code":"Authorization_RequestDenied","message":{"lang":"en","value":"Access to change password operation is denied."},...}}`

For updating another info of user and reset password it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Actually its possible for a B2C user to change its own password. Get an standard (non B2C) AAD access token with *scope=Directory.AccessAsUser.All* using your upn (usually something like *objectid@b2ctenantfullname*, [you can get this querying AAD Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations#get-users--) too) and call the [ChangeUserPassword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/api/functions-and-actions#changePassword) api. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

As per [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet?tabs=applications), did you grant your application the User administrator role? This gives your application the ability to delete users or update passwords.

Comment: Yes, I did. But it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the **GraphClient.ChangeUserPassword** method invokes [the **changePassword** action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/api/functions-and-actions#changePassword) that only allows the signed-in user to change their own password.

This isn't possible for an Azure AD B2C local account user.

Instead, you must `PATCH` [the **passwordProfile** property for the user object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations#reset-a-users-password--) such as:

```
PATCH https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/users/{user_id}?api-version=1.6
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "passwordProfile": {
    "forceChangePasswordNextLogin": false,
    "password": "Test1234"
  }
}
```

Note that it's important to set the **forceChangePasswordNextLogin** property to **false** otherwise the local account user can't be logged in to.

Comment: I've already implemented reset password using update password profile, but how to check in this case old user password?

Comment: Hi @IliaKhapaev Do you want to compare the new password with the current password and/or an older password?

Comment: I ask user to input older and new password, and I want to compare older password with password from b2c. But as I understand it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to set a new password for a user with the following code

```
public async Task SetUserPassword(string userId)
{
    var toUpdate = await _activeDirectoryClient.Users.GetByObjectId(userId).ExecuteAsync();
    toUpdate.PasswordProfile = new PasswordProfile
    {
        Password = "test!345G",
        ForceChangePasswordNextLogin = false
    };
    await toUpdate.UpdateAsync();
}
```

Comment: Yes, I also used same code for reset password. But if user want to change password as self he should input old password.